# AWS ebextensions creating httpd.conf with logfomat change as described in AWS document. But apache logs are printing twice

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ebextensions

I am using AWS ElasticBeanstalk for prod deployment.

I want to add response time for each request in apache access log.
As per AWS documentation I created a configuration file in source bundle `.ebextensions/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (took the default file and modified logformat)

The response time gets generated, but the log statements are printing twice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any solution for this?